# Authentication should not be null in unit tests with spring-session

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test, spring-session

I have a spring boot (version 1.5.9.RELEASE) application which uses spring-session to store sessions on Redis. It also uses spring-security to authenticate users. When running the application, after a successful login, the security context contains the Authentication object. But when running unit tests I get this error message `Authentication should not be null`. Code to reproduce is the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoRedisDataSessionApplication {

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableRedisHttpSession(redisNamespace = "demo-redis-spring-session")
    public static class AppConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("0000").roles("USER");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.formLogin().and()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        }

    }

    @RestController
    public static class AppController {

        @GetMapping("/secured")
        public String secured() {
            return "secured";
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoRedisDataSessionApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is application.properties

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
```

Here is the failing test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class DemoRedisDataSessionApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testUserShouldBeAuthenticated() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(formLogin().user("user").password("0000"))
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andExpect(authenticated());
    }

}
```

Error message for the failed test:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Authentication should not be null

    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:35)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.response.SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers$AuthenticatedMatcher.match(SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers.java:98)
```

In particular it seems that the session is null in the class `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` line 110, but I don't understand why.

I expect the user to be authenticated and the `SecurityContext` populated after a successful login. Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

## Updated:

Firstly, you need to instruct your authentication provider (in your case, it is the default `DaoAuthenticationProvider`) to return what kind of `Authentication` object. For instance, you can add `httpBasic()` into your `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method in your customized `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Essentially, httpBasic() will convert your username and password to a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken object such that your DaoAuthenticationProvider can use it to do authentication.

In addition, you need to `permitAll` for you login url.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
```

With regards to the unit test, the issue was due to the fact that you didn't wire-in spring security into your mockMvc object. As you are actually spring-boot, I would give you a sample solution with spring-boot-test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class DemoRedisDataSessionApplicationTests {

@Autowired
WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
}

@Test
public void testUserShouldBeAuthenticated() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(formLogin().user("user").password("0000"))
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
            .andExpect(authenticated());
}
}
```

Key Note: `springSecurity()` in the code above is from `import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I get the same error even with your proposed solution... I think the problem is that the `spring-session` library does not integrate very well with unit tests.

Comment: shouldn't be related to spring-session for this specific error... could your try to add `httpBasic()` in your AppConfiguration's `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception` method?

Comment: Fabio, I mean this:  `@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.formLogin().and()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
        }`

Comment: With `httpBasic()` it works fine, but unfortunately we cannot use it... we need to stick to `formLogin()`

Comment: Fabio, these 2 concepts don't clash with each other. `formLogin()` is to provide a implicit login page for your application, whereas `httpBasic()` is to provide a way for your authentication provider to authenticate the user. Essentially, `httpBasic()` will convert your username and password to a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` object such that your `DaoAuthenticationProvider` can use it to do authentication.